# How many functions, $f(x) = f'(x)$?

Tags: calculus

How many functions exist where their derivative is equal to the original function. For example:

$y = 0$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

$y = e^x$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = e^x$

Are there any other examples of these?

Comment: Exactly the functions in the form $f_\alpha(x)=\alpha\cdot e^x$ for some $\alpha\in\Bbb R$. How familiar are you with ordinary differential equations?

Comment: you have forgotten to add a constant

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, I did not, because that constant would vanish from the derivative. Or were you talking to the OP?